# Dynamic Jar loading is confusing me

Tags: java, classloader

Conceptually, what am I doing when I'm loading a new Jar? Is URLClassloader the only choice? How should I form those URLs to point to a subdirectory containing more jars.

If anyone is feeling super-generous, some demonstration code to do the following would be really helpful (let's assume "jars/A.jar" contains "myClass" which we want to instantiate):

1. load some jar from a subdirectory
2. return a particular class from it
3. instantiate that class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Conceptually, what am I doing when I'm loading a new Jar?

Conceptually, you are not loading a new JAR.  Rather, you are defining a class loader which will load code and other resources from the JAR file on demand.

> Is URLClassloader the only choice?

In theory, you could implement your own subclass of `ClassLoader`, but that's not necessary for what you are trying to do.

> How should I form those URLs to point to a subdirectory containing more jars.

This is the nub of your problem I think.  The [`URLClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) constructors interpret the `URL[]` argument as follows:

> *"Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be downloaded and opened as needed."*

In the first case of the quoted text above, the directory is assumed to be the root of tree containing resources to be loaded.

But I gather you are trying to set up a class loader that will load from all JAR files in a given directory.  To do that, you need to:

1. Read the directory and build a list of the `File` objects for any JAR files.
2. Create an array to hold the same number of `URL` instances.
3. For each JAR file `File`, use `File.toURL()` to create a `URL` and add to the array.  (Using `File.toURL()` means that you will get kosher "file:" URLs for the JAR files that will work on your platform.)
4. Create the `URLClassLoader` using the `URL` array.

Answer (score 2):

Really short version: when you load a new JAR, you're giving Java a new place to look for  classes.

For a longer explanation, Wikipedia has an article related to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader

Also, might try: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html

URLClassLoader is not your only choice; check out http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/apiindex.html

Re: how URLs should be formed, from the Java documentation (http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html):

> This class loader is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs referring to both JAR files and directories. Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be opened as needed.

Adapted from [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime):

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (new URL("jars/A.jar"), this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.myClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("myMethod");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance ();
Object result = method.invoke (instance);
```

Also, the answer linked above lists a few more alternatives to URLClassLoader (they mention OSGi, JCL, and a few others, none of which I have any experience with or I'd say something here).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If the list of jars is known then a potentially better/easier solution would be to just add a Class-Path entry to the parent jar's manifest. That way you avoid mucking around with custom classloaders completely.

```
Class-Path: jars/A.jar
```

Obviously this won't work where the dependent jars aren't known at build time.

Comment: how exactly does that 'dynamically' load?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to make sure the dependent JARs are in the classpath before starting the program.

---

If you want to load from a sub-directory, you need to determine the path of the JAR to give to the URLClassLoader.  You can use something like this to get the path to your program:

```
new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath())
```

It's a bit of a hack but I don't know of any official way to get the path to a Java program.

---

If you want to dynamically load a JAR such that you can use it as if you had specified it in the classpath, check out this [thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=300557&start=0&tstart=0).  It's definitely in the realm of unsupported hack, but it's also simple and easy.

Modified version that I use:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

/**
 * Hack to modify classpath at runtime. Can be used to load JARs as if they were
 * loaded from the start.
 * 
 * Warning: May break if URLClassLoader changes
 * 
 * @author Antony Miguel
 */
public class ClasspathHacker {
    /**
     * Add a file to the classpath.
     * 
     * @param pPath
     *            path to the file
     */
    public static void addFile(String pPath) {
        File f = new File(pPath);
        addFile(f);
    }

    /**
     * Add a file to the classpath.
     * 
     * @param pFile
     *            the file to be added
     */
    public static void addFile(File pFile) {
        try {
            addURL(pFile.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the content pointed to by a URL to the classpath.
     * 
     * @param pURL
     *            the URL pointing to the content to be added
     */
    public static void addURL(URL pURL) {
        /*
         * Use reflection to call addURL on the system classloader, which we
         * expect to be a URLClassLoader
         */
        Method method;
        try {
            method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",
                    new Class[] { URL.class });
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),
                    new Object[] { pURL });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```